# VC++ 2010, how to set file path

Tags: visual-c++, path

Let's say, I want to do:

```
load_image( "background.png" )
```

And background.png is located at C:\mypics\background.png

QUESTION: How do I set C:\mypics\ to be on the search path?? (like the way I add lib/include path)

Because I really don't want to do

```
load_image( "C:\\mypics\\background.png" )
```

And I also don't want to copy background.png into the project folder.

Comment: See the [`_chdir`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function, or [`SetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the "native" WIN32 function.

Comment: why not add the image as a resource in your executable or better yet, create a resource dll

Comment: I think Joachim Pileborg's answer is close enough to what I was searching for. So, thank you for the answer. @joachim-pileborg